# Read file which names changes everyday

Tags: powershell-2.0

Need help with part of this PS script. I am basically need to read the content of a file (look for word imported). New file is generated every day with the format power_XX.log 
XX represents the day of the month.
Don't know what I am overlooking , but if the file exists and word "imported" is found it should generated a true. 
Thanks in advance

```
 ************************
#today is a working day
    $today = (get-date).day
$fileofday = Get-ChildItem -Path \\noctest1\c$\temp\*.log ('power_' + $today + '.log')
if ($fileofday -and (select-string -Path '\\noctest1\c$\temp\*.log ($fileofday)'-Pattern 'imported' -Quiet))
*******************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$today = (get-date).day;
$filePath = join-path -path "\\noctest1\c`$\temp" -childpath $("power_$today.log");
$importedFound = $false;
$todayFileExists = test-path $filePath
if ($todayFileExists) {
    $importedFound = select-string $filePath -pattern "imported" -quiet;
}
```

`$importedFound` is now true if the file was found and contains "imported", otherwise it's false.